# Source of venue data behind iOS reverse geocoding

Tags: ios7, reverse-geocoding

I noticed that the "moves" app has fairly decent venues information, and then read that the iPhone provides reverse geocoding services through iOS.  What database of place & venue information is behind this?

Comment: [Apple maps data providers](http://screenwerk.com/2012/06/11/who-are-the-apple-maps-data-providers-here-they-are/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the move app uses foursquare for its "places" / venue layer, and not the Apple iOS CoreLocation service.